# Is ganache decentralised?

Tags: blockchain, dapps, ganache

According to Dapp the blockchain should distributed, But while we use ganache it runs on a local machine and the clients will be having only their private key and public key (or wallet) with them *AFAIK*. Will all the clients using dapp have their own copy of **blockchain** and i'm asking this since ganache is running on the host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gananche is a test chain and it is not decentralised.

Gananche is intended for software development purposes only and is not a production system.

Comment: This. I'd add that it's running locally on your machine.

Comment: Then, is it possible to create a decentralised private block chain with geth like any testnet(ropsten,rinkeby etc) for private use?

Comment: Yes. There are multiple tutorials on this.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa can you suggest some resource to set a private block chain for dapp

Comment: Please let's move the discussion out from the comments and open a new question.